# MySQL: How to divide

Tags: mysql, math, select

Im trying to make a select query that does the following:

```
Doelvoorraad - voorraad - al_besteld / Bestelgrootte.
```

And show the outcome as a new column called "Aantal".

```
SELECT `Bestelgrootte`,
       `Doelvoorraad`-`voorraad` - `al_besteld`/`Bestelgrootte`  AS `aantal` 
FROM `care_voorraad`
```

Comment: It doesn't divide the outcome of the three columns.

Comment: Divide by zero will be a problem. Use brackets for the order of the subtraction vs division

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems in your query, but this query below will work:

```
SELECT `Bestelgrootte`,
       (`Doelvoorraad`-`voorraad` - `al_besteld`)/`Bestelgrootte`  AS `aantal` 
FROM `care_voorraad`
WHERE `Bestelgrootte` <> 0
```

Note the brackets to ensure the subtraction ( - ) is done first.

1 - Use brackets as above

2 - You will encounter divide by zero.  Either use the `WHERE` clause to avoid zero, or a `CASE / IF` statement - whatever works in MySQL